# $\int_0^1 |F_X^{-1}(q) - F_Y^{-1}(q)| dq = \int_\mathbb R |F_X(x) - F_Y(x)| dx$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let X,Y be one-dimensional variables. I would like to prove that fact that $$\int_0^1 |F_X^{-1}(q) - F_Y^{-1}(q)| dq = \int_\mathbb R |F_X(x) - F_Y(x)| dx$$

where $F_X$ denotes cumulative distribution function of variable $X$ and $F_X^{-1}$ denotes quantile function.

**My work so far**

For sure this equality can be proven by only changing the variables in integrals. I tried to do

$q = F_X(x)$, then $dq = f(x) dx$, where $f(x)$ is a probability density function. Therefore;

$$\int_0^1 |F_X^{-1}(q) - F_Y^{-1}(q)| = \int_{\mathbb R}|(x - F_Y^{-1}(F_X(x)))|f(x)dx$$

which unforunetly is not exacly what I was looking for. Could you please give me a hand in proving this fact?

**EDIT**

I found out, that those integrals are equal to area between graphs $F_X$ and $F_Y$, however I'm not sure how it can be proven.

Comment: Try using [Inverse function Integration](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseFunctionIntegration.html)

Answer (score 2):

Does this count as a proof without words?

[image]

Comment: How do you treat the case where $F_X$ or $F_Y$ is not strictly increasing?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo As with a discrete distribution, you then get some horizontal line segments plus some vertical boundaries to the area (the vertical lines are not the function but in effect join two parts of the function). The reflection in the diagonal works in exactly the same way turning the horizontal segments into vertical boundaries and the vertical boundaries into horizontal segments, still preserving the area between the two CDFs or quantile functions